# OS X Mavericks, Cannot install libxml-ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, nokogiri, libxml2

On a clean install of Mac OS 10.9, jumping from 10.7.5, I seem incapable of installing the libxml-ruby gem. I use Homebrew and RVM to manage my environment, and I've installed the following things:

```
brew list

apple-gcc42 gcc46       libmpc08    mpfr2       postgresql
autoconf    gmp4        libtool     mysql55     ppl011
automake    libgpg-error    libxml2     openssl     readline
cloog-ppl015    libiconv    libxslt     ossp-uuid   wget
cmake       libksba     libyaml     pkg-config
```

Entering `brew doctor` returns:

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Running `bundle install` yields the following, where I've removed the links. I can't post more than two without 10 reputation apparently:

```
Fetching source index from . . .
Fetching source index from . . .
Fetching source index from . . .
Resolving dependencies..............................................................................................
Using rake (10.0.4) 
Using Platform (0.4.0) 
Using open4 (1.3.0) 
Using POpen4 (0.1.4)
```

etc., eventually reaching:

```
Using nokogiri (1.5.9)
```

etc.

```
Installing libxml-ruby (2.3.3) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/iandonovan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-opt-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/
extconf.rb:17: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname() in -lnsl... no
checking for atan() in -lm... no
checking for atan() in -lm... yes
checking for inflate() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile
make
compiling libxml.c
compiling ruby_xml.c
ruby_xml.c: In function 'rxml_default_tree_indent_string_set':
ruby_xml.c:612:23: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
compiling ruby_xml_attr.c
compiling ruby_xml_attr_decl.c
ruby_xml_attr_decl.c: In function 'rxml_attr_decl_name_get':
ruby_xml_attr_decl.c:57:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'rxml_new_cstr' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
ruby_xml_encoding.h:11:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'const xmlChar *'
compiling ruby_xml_attributes.c
compiling ruby_xml_cbg.c
compiling ruby_xml_document.c
ruby_xml_document.c: In function 'rxml_document_canonicalize':
ruby_xml_document.c:232:10: warning: unused variable 'list_in' [-Wunused-variable]
ruby_xml_document.c:334:3: warning: passing argument 4 of 'xmlC14NDocDumpMemory' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/c14n.h:76:3: note: expected 'xmlChar **' but argument is of type 'xmlChar * (*)[256]'
ruby_xml_document.c:199:7: warning: variable 'length' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ruby_xml_document.c: In function 'rxml_document_root_set':
ruby_xml_document.c:757:14: warning: variable 'xroot' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ruby_xml_document.c: In function 'rxml_document_save':
ruby_xml_document.c:805:13: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
compiling ruby_xml_dtd.c
compiling ruby_xml_encoding.c
compiling ruby_xml_error.c
compiling ruby_xml_html_parser.c
compiling ruby_xml_html_parser_context.c
ruby_xml_html_parser_context.c: In function 'rxml_html_parser_context_options_set':
ruby_xml_html_parser_context.c:307:7: warning: variable 'result' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
compiling ruby_xml_html_parser_options.c
compiling ruby_xml_input_cbg.c
compiling ruby_xml_io.c
compiling ruby_xml_namespace.c
compiling ruby_xml_namespaces.c
compiling ruby_xml_node.c
ruby_xml_node.c: In function 'rxml_node_to_s':
ruby_xml_node.c:622:54: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ruby_xml_node.c:624:56: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make: *** [ruby_xml_node.o] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/iandonovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@standard-set/gems/libxml-ruby-2.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/iandonovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@standard-set/gems/libxml-ruby-2.3.3/ext/libxml/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (2.3.3), and Bundler cannot continue
Make sure that `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.3.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Running that standalone gem install, `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.3.3'`, returns the same error message.

XCode 5.0.1 is installed, alongside the developer tools. I could not install the dev tools through `xcode-select --install` because of "A network problem" (according to the dialog box) and instead downloaded the Mavericks package from developer.apple.com.

Has anyone else dealt with this? Nokogiri appears to be installing just fine (1.5.9 gets bundled), but libxml-ruby can't finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of libxml-ruby being installed is too old to be compatible with the libxml2 version.  Presumably you've got the latest libxml2 version - 2.9.1.

libxml-ruby isn't compatible with libxml2 2.9.x until version 2.4.0.  You can find additional information here - https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/blob/master/HISTORY .

Why are you installing such an old version of libxml-ruby?  If you try installing a more recent version it should work fine.

Comment: We definitely have to update our gemfile, and this event is as good a catalyst as any. Thanks.

Comment: If you must use a version earlier than 2.4.0, you could manually implement this diff as a patch: https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/commit/1c4878f3fdcd0cdf2e0fd09a5e6147a6ed237cf0